# Overloading input the base class inside overloading input derived class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to reuse a overloading input functions from `Base` class inside `Derived` class.

```
class Base
{
private:
    int m_value;

public:
    Base(int value)
        : m_value(value)
    {
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in,Base &b)
    {

        in>>b.m_value;
        return in;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    std::string id;
public:
    Derived(int value,std::string id)
        : Base(value),id(id)
    {
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in,Derived &d)
    {
        in>>static_cast<Base>(d);//not work
        in>>d.id;
        return in;
    }
};
```

What wrong with my code when I write `in>>static_cast<Base>(d)`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the `Base` part of `d`, you need to cast to `Base&`.
What you get with your cast is a temporary `Base` object, which can't be passed as a non-const reference argument.

Note that this cast will still not make everything work as you would expect – for instance,

```
Derived d;
Base &b = d;
std::cin >> b;
```

will use the `Base&` overload, since overloading is based on the static type of `b`.

A common way to overload `>>` (and `<<`) for a hierarchy is to have only one overload, which just delegates to a virtual member function.
Then you can override the member function in the derived classes and let dynamic dispatch take care of selecting the appropriate function.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void read(std::istream& is) { ... }
};

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Base &b)
{
    b.read(in);
    return in;
}

struct Derived: Base
{
    void read(std::istream& is) override { Base::read(is); ... }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
static_cast<Base>(d);
```

you get a `Base` prvalue that has the base part of `d`.  You can't pass that to

```
friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in,Base &b)
```

though since it needs an lvalue.  What you need to do is get a reference to the `Base` part of `d` instead like

```
in >> static_cast<Base&>(d);
```